# Docker not starting on Windows 10

Tags: docker, ubuntu

After installing docker Desktop on windows , the docker fails to start even though I have wsl2 installed

```
 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

What are the steps that I should take to fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Docker on windows with WSL2 you need to enable virtualization on BIOS settings and configure WSL2 on Docker Desktop.

To check the WSL mode, run:

```
wsl.exe -l -v
```

To upgrade your existing Linux distro to v2, run:

```
wsl.exe --set-version (distro name) 2
```

To set v2 as the default version for future installations, run:

```
wsl.exe --set-default-version 2
```

[How to enable virtualization on BIOS](https://www.virtualmetric.com/blog/how-to-enable-hardware-virtualization)

[How to run Docker desktop with WSL2](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).